# Javascript value to hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a function that sets a date on change to a hidden field. I am currently receiving and populating a field with a date from the server. When i submit the field without a change it is returning as an empty string even though it does originally display a date. How can i make sure that the displayed date gets saved back to server if no change is made?

```
$(":asp(LeadEffectiveDate)").change(function () {
    var effectiveDate = $(":asp(LeadEffectiveDate)").val();
    $(":asp(LeadEffectiveDateToSetForUserRole)").val(effectiveDate);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date is already being populated inside a page load function add the 
     there.

```
$(":asp(LeadEffectiveDateToSetForUserRole)").val(effectiveDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read it on the document ready event. Update it when the dropdown changes.

```
$(function(){

  var effectiveDate = $(":asp(LeadEffectiveDate)").val();
  $(":asp(LeadEffectiveDateToSetForUserRole)").val(effectiveDate);

  $(":asp(LeadEffectiveDate)").change(function () {

     effectiveDate = $(":asp(LeadEffectiveDate)").val();
     $(":asp(LeadEffectiveDateToSetForUserRole)").val(effectiveDate);

  });

});
```

On a side note, I personally prefer to do my jQuery selectors with an Id attribute (`$("#SomeUniqueId")`).

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thanks alot!